# ASP.NET MVC 5: Can not access column from controller if it is not displayed in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a newbie to ASP.NET MVC 5 and i am developing a simple app.

I have two fields(UserCreatedId. UserUpdatedId) in my model which i want to create/update them in controller and they are not displayed in view.

When i try to access these fields from Edit action they show up null and this causes a foreign key conflict.

View:

```
@model AuditTrackingApp.Models.Company

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Şirket Bilgilerini Düzenle";
}

@section navigationMenu{
    <nav>
        @{ Html.RenderAction("GetNavMenuItems", "Home"); }
    </nav>
}

<h2>Şirket Bilgilerini Düzenle</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyName, "Şirket Adı", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyAddress, "Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CompanyAddress1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyAddress1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyCountry, "Ülke", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyCountry, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyCountry, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyCity, "İl", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyCounty, "İlçe", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyCounty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyCounty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyZipCode, "Posta Kodu", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreationTime, "Oluşturulma Zamanı", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreationTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreationTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UpdateTime, "Güncellenme Zamanı", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UpdateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UpdateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="DEĞİŞİKLİKLERİ KAYDET" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Şirket Listesine Dön", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Company company = db.Companies.Find(id);
    if (company == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(company);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CompanyId,CompanyName,CompanyAddress,CompanyCountry,CompanyCity,CompanyCounty,CompanyZipCode,UserCreatedId,CreationTime,UserUpdatedId,UpdateTime")] Company company)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;

        //HardCoded for UserCreatedId and UserUpdatedId now. UserId will be taken from session later
        User user = (from i in db.Users where i.UserId == 1 select i).SingleOrDefault();

        int companyToUpdateId = company.CompanyId;
        Company companyToUpdate = (from i in db.Companies where i.CompanyId == companyToUpdateId select i).SingleOrDefault();
        company.UserCreatedId = companyToUpdate.UserCreatedId;
        company.UserUpdatedId = user.UserId;
        company.UpdateTime = DateTime.Now;

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(company);
}
```

I know i can ignore these two fields by `IsModified` property on update then update will be okay. I just want to understand why i can't access these columns from database while they are already set up. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you also show the code of your view?

Comment: @jvanrhyn will edit hold on please

Comment: Try adding the fields to the view as hidden fields. `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserCreatedId);`

Comment: Yes i can do that but just trying to understand why i can't access data in controller when i am querying to database ?

Comment: You said, in the `View` that hey are null. And you want to understand why they are null. Well you have to provide us the non HTTPpost attribute because, your view started there not in the HTTPpost Edit method.

Comment: Can you please also post your models?

Comment: @Aizen also provided the GET Edit Action

Comment: Shouldn't it be `companyToUpdate.UserCreatedId = company.UserCreatedId;`, etc? In your code, `companyToUpdate` isn't modified.

Comment: @GertArnold As i mentioned in the question `company.UserCreatedId` is null. That is the problem so can not query like this.

Comment: Yes, I understand your problem, and I think Stralos's answer tackles that. But supposing you get this right, I'm a bit puzzled how you can attach `company` (by `db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;`) and then fetch the same company again (`companyToUpdate`) while it doesn't seem to play any role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @jvanrhyn inside your question comments. IF you want *UserCreatedId* and *UserUpdatedId* to NOT be nulls, those fields have to be inside your form.

If you do not want to display them, then you should use @Html.HiddenFor() helper, or plain on old HTML.

The problem is that once you submit a form, **only** things that are inside your `<form>` get submitted. Your form does NOT have these fields, so when you submit it, *UserCreatedId* and *UserUpdatedId* are set to null by default.

EDIT:

@Tartar you have a couple of options.

1. One would be to use Html.HiddenFor(), inside your form. The data
   will not be displayed on your view, but it will still be in your
   form, so when you'll submit it, you will have values inside
   UserCreatedId and UserUpdatedId. This solution is good, when you
   need a fast and easy fix.
2. Another solution would be to implement an IRepository pattern
   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repository-pattern-done-right

   Then instead of db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified; you
   could use a generic method to get your company data by a single
   primary key(for example companyId) like:

   ```
   public TEntity Get(string id) where TEntity : class
       {
           return _session.Get<TEntity>(id);
       }
   ```

   once you'll have the data from your database, you'll just update the
   values you want. Implementing IRepository pattern might be a little
   bit of an overkill, but it's a good pattern to know and it's good
   practice.
3. Last option I could think of is to display those values, but make
   them disabled inside your view(do not allow to edit them). This is
   the easiest fix, but it's a lazy fix.

Overall it depends on what you want to achieve, if you would clarify what is the purpose of your app(learning project, school project, work) I would be able to give you a more detailed solution : )

EDIT:
After looking up your code I came up with a fast and good(I guess) solution:

```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Company company)
    {

    try{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           var companyToUpdate = db.Companies.Find(company.companyId).FirstOrDefault();
            /../
            /some update logic or what you need to do. companyToUpdate has ALL the values you need./
            /../

            db.Update(companyToUpdate);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(company);
}catch(Exception ex){
//do something if exception occurs.
}

    }
```

Comment: Makes sense. What should i do to accsess these fields from controller by sending a linq query to db as i already did in the Edit Post action ? It also does not work.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of directly using your `Model` classes, create a `ViewModel` class, that only has the fields you want on your view, and then validate against that.  In the controller you can map the fields to the model (User), and add in any computed values or extra foreign key mappings.

Dont use hidden fields for things you want to be computed, as the client can manipulate them.  you can use `ModelState.Remove("[Field name you do not want validated]");` to stop it validating any fields.

Comment: You have to understand that. The question is why. Not How. He wants to get clarification, not a solution.

Comment: @Aizen Fair enough.  It's important to understand the implications of using hidden fields, and the level of trust you should (or not) give to them, because they can be fabricated by a malicious client.